# RAD project reference/class not found

Tags: eclipse, reference, websphere, project, dependency-management

I have three projects, let's call them A, B, and C in RAD (Eclipse).  A is a simple java project with supporting code that both B and C will consume.  B and C are both webapps that will run on WebSphere.

I wrote B, which includes A as a project reference in the build path, and includes it in the Deployment Assembly to be placed as a jar in the web-inf/lib.  This works more or less perfectly.

C is a pre-existing project that someone else wrote that I must apply the same code to.  I try the same trick (I thought) and while it finds A for compile time, when I publish to the test environment class not founds.  When I export an ear, I find that C has the jar that represents A, and in a similar location.  HOWEVER, C has a lib directory in the root of the jar (adjacent to the wars).  The A.jar is inside the lib inside one of the wars.

I've never seen this extra lib folder in other deployments and have been scouring the setting and have NO IDEA where it came from.

So my questions are:
1) Does anyone know what is producing that root lib folder
but more importantly...
2) Any idea why my classes can't be found...I presume this extra lib is messing it up somehow, but A.jar IS in the web-inf/lib of C.war.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the `library-directory` of the EAR and contains utility jars that can be accessed by all modules.  It defaults to 'lib' but can be changed.

You should edit the ear file using a zip tool -

- If A.jar is required by both WARs, then try it in the lib folder.  It should not contain any code that is required to within the WAR
- Else, edit the ear file and take it out of the lib folder

Comment: Oops, didn't see your response before writing my own.  You were actually dead on.  My question is why the war's web-inf/lib behavior would not work in the presence of this EAR lib.  Do you know why that might be?

Comment: I don't think the entire WEB-INF/lib stopped working.  It may be the specific jars. Glad that I may have been of some help.

Comment: Why would specific jars stop working? I presume that the EAR lib is searched first in the classpath, but if that behavior didn't prevent the war's web-inf/lib from being similarly processed, why would it pick some jars not to process?  As I said, I have resolved that specific issue, but I am keen to understand what went wrong better.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  Here's what happened.  Unbeknownst to me, a co-worker actually created a secondary lib directory unthe ear project because he was planning to deploy a second war under that ear, and wanted a shared library place.

I still don't understand this next part.  For some reason, this lib directory didn't just ADD TO the classpath, but seemingly superceded the web-inf/lib where A.jar lived.  Since his project will also need A.jar (eventually), I am content to generate A.jar into that folder.  But I sure would like to understand why the web-inf/lib stopped working when this alternative lib was created.